# How to animate a flip of a card in Cocos2d?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I am working on a card game and would like to ask if someone could advice me how to implement a flip of a card in Cocos2D?

Comment: found a possible solution: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15771

Answer (score 2):

Flip animation in cocos2d-android-1 like that...

```
CCSprite sprite=CCSprite.sprite("icon.png");
CCIntervalAction a = (CCIntervalAction)CCOrbitCamera.action(2, 1, 0, 0, 360, 0, 0);
addChild(sprite,1);
sprite.runAction(CCRepeatForever.action(a));
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it using `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

ios objective-c version:

```
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Games1.png"];

player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

CCActionInterval *a = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:2 radius:1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:0 deltaAngleZ:360 angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0];
[self addChild:player];
[player runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:a]];
```

Comment: Answers that are just code without explanation are poor answers. They're not very good because they don't do much to help users learn.